# Retrieve mail addresses of nested distribution list via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to find out who is invited to an event via Microsoft Graph API v1.0. The event gives me a list of invitees, which can also contain distribution lists. This is fine, but I really want to know the mail addresses of each and every person invited to that meeting (directly or via DL).

In the case an invitee is a distribution list, the event gives me the following information: `"name": "DL Foo", "address": "DL_1234567890@global.corp.foo"`

My first idea was to get the id of the DL with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/?$filter=startswith(displayName,'DL Foo')` then list all of the members with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members` and do recursive calls in case any member is a nested DL.

I got an `Insufficient privileges` as an answer, so I can't try this for now.
Would this have been the preferred approach (then I'll lobby my organisation to change privileges)?

Is there a more elegant way to retrieve all invitees of an event via Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

It appears what are you after is [List group transitive members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-transitivemembers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint which:

> Get a list of the group's members. A group can have users, devices,
>   organizational contacts, and other groups as members. This operation
>   is transitive and returns a *flat list of all nested members*.

So, `GET /groups/{id}/transitiveMembers` should return a flat list of all nested members (including members of ‎Distribution list‎ group)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the correct API! Regarding the permissions, it looks like you need admin consent to use the groups API. Since my app works with user consent it looks like there is no way it can get the members of a DL :-( I don't really understand why user consent is insufficient? Any user can expand a DL in outlook with a double click. Why can't a user do the same via Graph API?

Comment: Even with a special "admin consent" for group.read.all it is not possible to get the group ID of a DL. Filtering with the display name simply does not work (e.g. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName,'DL foo'). So it looks like I cannot use the list group transitive members endpoint if I only know the name and mail address of a DL :-(

Comment: My bad, as documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-transitivemembers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http you need an additional scope (and admin consent): for User.ReadBasic.All. I still don't understand why the admin consent is required, but once you have it, you can actually read DLs :-)